# SSRS report not showing image from DB

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table with varbinary(MAX) field to store images.
I have updated this table with the following SQL:

```
insert into table1
select * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\capture.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img
```

Select from this table looks like this:

[image]

I have created a dataset that pulls this image from the table:

```
select * from table1
```

Then for the image I use from database and this is its source  in the expression:

```
=First(Fields!Image.Value, "DataSet1")
```

MIME is image/png

The image is not showing in the report. All I get is the red X.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If it was a PNG file then the first eight bytes would be `0x89504e470d0a1a0a` because that's the signature required for PNG format images. So what is it really?

Comment: Yes, it was PNG. What worked for me is Base64 string inserted into a table and then converted from Base64 in the report.